# Adding object to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist

I'm trying to add objects received from Firebase Database to an ArrayList. However, the list stays empty even after calling the add method. What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to load data from firebase and is display it in a list view. I used log statements to check if the data from firebase is being received  and it is. Anybody with suggestions?

```
public class RescueFragment extends Fragment {

    public RescueFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rescue_list, container, false);

        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("rescue");

        final ArrayList<RescueAnimal> rescueList = new ArrayList<>();

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String location = (String) messageSnapshot.child("location").getValue();
                    String appearance = (String) messageSnapshot.child("appearance").getValue();
                    String photo = (String) messageSnapshot.child("photo").getValue();
                    String species = (String) messageSnapshot.child("species").getValue();
                    String problem = (String) messageSnapshot.child("problem").getValue();
                    rescueList.add(new RescueAnimal(location, appearance, photo, species, problem));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        RescueAdapter adapter = new RescueAdapter(getActivity(), rescueList);
        ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.rescue_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
```

Comment: Where is the list being used? How do you know it's empty?

Comment: Your `onDataChange` function executes asynchronously. Therefore you are calling .add after you use the list. Add a print statements before `rescueList.add` and `RescueAdapter adapter = new RescueAdapter(getActivity(), rescueList);` to see what's happening.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint inside the `for` loop when you were debugging your code, so ensure that it is executing? Or a Log statement?

Comment: did you run this in debug mode?

Comment: I used the function isEmpty() to print in the Log if its empty. And it worked. Moreover nothing gets displayed in the fragment because adapter is being fed an empty arraylist

Comment: @StevenWexler what should I do to load and display the data then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `null` because you are declaring the `rescueList` ArrayList outside the `onDataChange()`. This is happening due the asynchronous behaviour of this method. This means that the statement that adds those objects to the ArrayList is executed before `onDataChange()` method has been called. To solve this you need to declare and use that `ArrayList` inside `onDataChange()`. Be careful not to add inside the for loop.

If you want to use those values outside that method, i sugget you readning my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange).

Comment: I'm using notifyDataSetChanged() but its rather slow on updating or when initializing. Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: You can take a look at [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android). Everything is happening in real time.